# Why does PyCharm throw type-hint wigglies when I decorate a nested class with `@dataclass`?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, python-dataclasses

I am using Python's support for nested classes to group and organise class definitions. Some of these inner classes are pure data classes and I am benefitting from the boilerplate reduction of @dataclass (`__init__`, `__repr__` etc).

Unfortunately, when I try to create an instance of the inner class, PyCharm can't seem to get the arguments' type hinting correct and puts a wigglie (wiggly line indicating, usually, poor code) under the first argument. Note that:

- The code runs fine, this is just an issue with type hinting.
- `@dataclass` on a module level class produces no such issue.
- Removing `@dataclass` and manually inserting the boilerplate for `__init__`

Here is a screenshot of the code with PyCharm's warning:
[image]

Comment: Odd... it's as if it thinks `Inner` is a method. This sounds like a bug.

Comment: This is a bug. A work around, for the case where the Outer is purely for organisational purposes, is to use a hierarchy of modules. So `Outer.py` and inside that define `@dataclass class Inner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35698 (thumbs up near the title)